# How do I process captured output from `tail` without reprocessing?

Tags: perl, unix, iostream, tail

I want to excecute a `tail` command in Unix for indefinite time and capture its output in a Perl script, process it and store certain data into a database. But it should be live, meaning old data – once stored in the database – shouldn't be reprocessed. It should only capture, and process only the most recent output.

Can someone please tell me how can this be done? Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3):

Try [File::Tail](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Tail) which can handle multiple files at same time.